# Mixing metric distance with Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

By far the most elegant proof of uniqueness of limits in a metric space I've seen (though I can't find the stack exchange link where it originated) is as follows.

> Let $X$ be a metric space, $(p_n)$ a sequence in $X$, $p,p'$ limits. For any $n$, we have
> $$ 
> d(p,p') \leq d(p,p_n) + d(p_n, p'). 
> $$
> As $d(p,p_n) \to 0$ and $d(p_n, p') \to 0$, $d(p, p_n) + d(p_n, p') \to 0$, so by the squeeze lemma, $d(p,p') \to 0$. So $d(p,p') = 0$.

I believe the steps in this proof make sense to me. It uses the algebraic limit theorem to argue that the limit of a sum equals the sum of the limits on the right-hand side, the fact that distance is nonnegative, the squeeze lemma, and then the fact that $d(p,p')$ is constant over $n$, so if $d(p,p') \to 0$, $d(p,p') = 0$.

My question is: this proof seems to use the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$, regarding $d(p,p_n)$ and $d(p_n, p')$ as sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ in their own right. Why are we allowed to use the Euclidean metric? I believe that all metrics on $\mathbb{R}$ end up being equivalent, so this may not be a problem in $\mathbb{R}$, but what if I regarded them as sequences in $\mathbb{C}$, where I believe that isn't the case? In other words, is there any role played by the metric that is used, and does it in any way sacrifice generality to "choose" a metric on $\mathbb{R}$/$\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Nowhere does this proof use Euclidean metric and it is also not true that all metrics on $\mathbb R$ are equivalent. The discrete metric is not equivalent to  the usual metric.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the clarification. I'm a bit confused then. Don't we require a metric for a limit definition? I thought we could say that $d(p_n, p) \to 0$ because $\forall \epsilon > 0, \; \exists N, \; \forall n \geq N, \; |d(p_n, p) - 0| < \epsilon$, which uses the Euclidean metric. Is the metric arbitrary?

Comment: $(d(p_n,p))$ is  sequence of real numbers and its convergence is w.r.t. the usual metric. But that does not mean that $d$ is the Euclidean metric.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I understand that $d$ isn't the Euclidean metric. Sorry, I should have been clearer. I'm confused as to why we're allowed to use the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$ (which I assume is Euclidean) to consider the convergence of $(d(p_n, p))$.

Comment: That is a convention in all of Mathematics. Converegence of a sequence of real numbers is w.r.t. then usual metric unless some other metric is explicitly stated.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Though I understand that, is there any reason to believe that if we didn't use the Euclidean metric here, the result would change? I'm still not fully convinced by this result, even though I understand why each of the assertions hold in $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual metric.

Comment: Now that I think of it more, my assertion was that $d(p_n, p) \to 0$, but that was a statement with respect to the Euclidean metric, so I had to "continue" the analysis using that same metric.